# Is there a way to work background-size in IE7 and IE8 with maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image, aspect-ratio

I want to set a full screen background image on my webpage. I'm using background-size=cover for that. It gives me exactly what I want but it doesn't work in lt-IE9 so that i am using css filters.

```
#container{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background: url('img/dogs.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/dogs.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/dogs.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

But it only seems to stretch the image in order to fit it to background and distorts the aspect ratio of the image. Can someone please suggest any other solution? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: afaik this can only be archieved using javascript, does the solution have to be css only?

Comment: Yes, I need css only solution. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

For IE8:

Say you have an image 100px X 150px

Try adding

```
#container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 150%  /*height/width * 100% */;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Yzkju/1/)

### Markup

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 150%;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

NB: I tried runnning this on IE - but jsFiddle doesn't work in iE <9 mode.
So I'm not sure if this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

One CSS solution using htc file:

Download [backgroundsize.min.htc](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill/downloads) and put it inside your project.

Now simply add these lines in your css:

```
{
    //your other properties
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-behavior: url(backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

**NOTE: use the `url` according to your project setup.**

Enjoy this simple solution. **:)**

Answer (score 0):

You also try backstretch (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/), same result as `background-size:cover` and also allows for slideshows. You can use it on the body or the content.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".#container").backstretch("path/to/image.jpg");
</script>
```

or call it on the body

```
<script>
    $.backstretch("path/to/image.jpg");
</script>
```